# Application services functionality lost in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a ASP.NET application that uses application services to manage user roles.  This application worked fine when I was using a local database.  When I transitioned to Azure, the main data tables still work but I am unable have user's login or create new accounts because the Application table cannot be found.  Previously, the application services created these tables automatically when using a local database.  The connection string name appears accurate.  This is my first attempt at Azure...is there something I'm missing?

The error is "The entity type Application is not part of the model for the current context"

For additional context:  When I try to create the membership tables in the Azure database using aspnet_regsql.exe, I get the following error:  "An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallCommon.sql'. The SQL error number is 40508 and the SqlException message is: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database."

Comment: `is there something I'm missing`  Please have a try to deploy to Azure App Service following the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database)

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT: I've went through that tutorial and it doesn't appear to have fixed the issue.  I'm hoping it isn't because I'm misconstruing details between MVC and this legacy WebForms app that is causing the issue.  I've checked my connectionStringName within the <providers> section of the web.config file and it seems to be correct.  This connection works fine to write to the existing database tables, but when it comes time for the provider to generate the tables through an automatic SQL script, the membership tables never get created.